# Which version of window phone sdk I need?

Tags: sdk, windows-phone

I have windows 8 - 32 bit system. Which version of sdk I need to install?
Any other option to install windows phone sdk in window 8 32 bits?
Where I get windows sdk for windows8 32bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

Start from [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us)! And you understand all.

for [wp7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

```
System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Vista

Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter Edition
Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition
Installation requires 4 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
3 GB RAM
Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver

The Windows Phone SDK 7.1 is compatible with the final version of Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
```

for [wp8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

```
System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro

Operating system type:
Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
Hardware:
6.5 GB of free hard disk space
4 GB RAM
64-bit (x64) CPU
Windows Phone 8 Emulator:
Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements, but does not meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator, the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.
```

Basically, you need Win 8 64x or Win7.

Comment: I tried windows sdk 7.1 from here.but it could not installed and said that "this program has compatibility issues"

Comment: Window Phone 8 sdk requires windows8 - 64 bit. I have windows8 -32 bit. how?

Comment: Check [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx). You can't use WP8 sdk on 32bit. Install WP7.1 sdk!

Comment: Thank you.Is there any other option to install in window8 32bits?

Comment: wp8 + win8(32bit) = 100% NO; wp7.1 + win8(32bit) = 100% NO